не могу разобраться с aiogram
хочу реализовать рандомайзер в бот, если сам рандомайзер я научился писать, то как его засунуть в тг бота я понятия не имею
не знаю даже что использовать вместо input дабы запросить число,второе,вывести рандомное
пытался смотреть некоторые гайды aiogram но не смог вникнуть, такое ощущение что эту библиотеку aiogram учить сложнее чем весь язык питон. может есть шарящие за тг ботов которые смогут объяснить? мне главное понять как это работает
и вообще можете разъяснить как выучить эту библиотеку и сколько времени на это нужно? я за целый учебный день понял лишь "message.reply" хотя думал что выучу всю библу за день лол. слишком медленный темп обучения?(
слишком сложно даются эти "DispetcherЫ" и прочее, как бы не разжевывали на ютубе или как бы не разжевывал чат gpt слишком сложно понять, сам язык было и то легче учить как мне показалось чем одну библиотеку
з.ы спустя пару дней я всё таки смог понять(хотя бы примерно) что такое Dispatcher и т.д, но мне всё равно говорят что я тупой и медленно учусь

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

для того, чтобы "запросить у пользователя число" изучайте и используйте FSM
